# Using Angular environment variables in workspace libraries

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I am using [workspaces](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace) concept of angular latest version(>6).

The CLI can generate a project that is a [library](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library) with a command like this:

```
ng generate library api
```

tsconfig.json of default app is like this

```
"paths": {
      "env": ["src/environments"],
      "api": [
        "dist/api"
      ],
```

After that I created one service named ApiService in api library like this but it's not working

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'env';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getApiUrl(){
    console.log("Hello Api Url"+environment.api_url)
}
}
```

Returns error when I build api library  using command `ng build api`:

```
BUILD ERROR
error TS6059: File 'ROOT_APP_PATH/src/environments/environment.ts'
is not under 'rootDir' 'ROOT_APP_PATH\projects\api\src'.
'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

please help to resolve this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add providedIn:

@Injectable({
  **providedIn: 'root'**
})

Comment: Thank for your suggestion but It's not working. BTW I understood this and I am able to build the library if I removed environment variable. So it's not about creating singleton service in root module. Also I am able to use that service in my root app. But when I tried getting  environment variable in that library, I am getting this error.

Comment: @NikhilChandu were you able to find any solution for this issue ? i have a couple of services to be imported into an angular library and i am facing the exact issue. any suggestions on how to fix this will be really helpful.

Comment: You can make "rootDir": "." or like that "rootDir": "../" on your tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 0):

By default `rootDir` is considered as the path of `tsconfig.json`

> It Specifies the root directory of input files. Only use to control the
>   output directory structure with --outDir.

[compiler options](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: I didn't get your point here. I have added environment in paths of root tsconfig.json as well, but it is searching environment  variable in library root but not the root project.

Comment: but environment path is by default configured  in angular project. angular.json

Comment: there is no need to separately  specify.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But I am not able to access that environment variable in my library. The same can be done using [link](https://nrwl.io/nx).
Please check this github link for sample example as well [link](https://github.com/stefanoslig/angular-ngrx-nx-realworld-example-app/blob/master/libs/api/src/lib/api.service.ts)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm running into the same issue. (Typescript 3.1.1)